# Wordpress Paypal Error after Paypal express checkout button is pressed

Tags: wordpress, express, woocommerce, paypal, payment

I'm getting an error such as this after updating Woocommerce to its latest version. 
PayPal error (10002): An error (10002) occurred while processing your PayPal payment. Please contact the store owner for assistance.

This is my error log:

```
06-05-2020 @ 15:33:45 - WC_Gateway_PPEC_Client::_request: remote request to https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp with params: Array
(
    [LOGOIMG] => https://public-health-safety.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/PHS-Logo-150x72.jpg
    [HDRIMG] => 
    [PAGESTYLE] => 
    [BRANDNAME] => PHS
    [RETURNURL] => https://public-health-safety.com/checkout/?woo-paypal-return=true
    [CANCELURL] => https://public-health-safety.com/cart/?woo-paypal-cancel=true
    [LANDINGPAGE] => Login
    [SOLUTIONTYPE] => Sole
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION] => sale
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INSURANCEAMT] => 0
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_HANDLINGAMT] => 0
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CUSTOM] => 
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INVNUM] => 
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE] => USD
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT] => 190
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT] => 190
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT] => 0
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT] => 0
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPDISCAMT] => 0
    [NOSHIPPING] => 0
    [EMAIL] => phsinc33@yahoo.com
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTONAME] =>  
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTREET] => 1528 W Adams
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTREET2] => 
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCITY] => Chicago
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTATE] => IL
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOZIP] => 60607
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE] => US
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOPHONENUM] => 3124910081
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0] => AA 20-0608 - Asbestos Awareness 4-hour Training CAMICB
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0] => ASBESTOS AWARENESS 4-HR TRAINING
Qualifies:  
Per requirement of Community Association Managers International Certification 
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0] => 2
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0] => 95
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0] => 
    [METHOD] => SetExpressCheckout
    [VERSION] => 120.0
    [USER] => 
    [PWD] => 
    [SIGNATURE] => 
)

06-05-2020 @ 15:33:45 - WC_Gateway_PPEC_Client::_process_response: acknowleged response body: Array
(
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2020-06-05T20:33:45Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => ca25e49242d8a
    [ACK] => Failure
    [VERSION] => 120.0
    [BUILD] => 54596016
    [L_ERRORCODE0] => 10002
    [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Authentication/Authorization Failed
    [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => You do not have permissions to make this API call
    [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
)
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though you need to set your API credentials (User/Password/Signature).

They can be obtained via https://www.paypal.com/api

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will take a look at it and let you know.

Comment: Yes, Paypal API credentials had to be added in. It worked! Thanks!